# Capturar error provocado en el intérprete por sintaxis erronea

Tags: php

Me he encontrado con un problema que me ha tenido de cabeza durante media hora, en la que he tenido parado el servicio con el que trabajo. El error, finalmente era simplemente que había usado mal la función `isset()`, pasándole como parámetro otra cosa que no fuese una variable, dando lugar a un error a la hora de interpretarse el código.

**Ejemplo del código que generó el error**

```
if(isset($this->input->post('ejemplo'))) {
    echo 'Ejecuta el código';
}
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: **¿Existe alguna manera de capturar este tipo de errores para que no deje de ejecutarse el resto del código?** He probado con todo tipo de métodos (`try/cach`, `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`), para tratar aunque sea de ver si consigo sacar el error por pantalla o consola, pero dudo que ninguno de estos métodos sirva, ya que el error ocurre en el intérprete, antes de que se llegue a ejecutar el código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar [`set_error_handler`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php):

> *[...]* Esta función se puede usar para definir su propia forma de manejar los errores en tiempo de ejecución *[...]*.

#### Ejemplo:

Si necesitas capturar **todos los "errores"** que ocurren en tu aplicación podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
function errorHandlerOff($errno, $errstr){
    return false;
}

function errorHandlerOn ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    //
    if ($errno == E_DEPRECATED || $errno == E_STRICT) {
        // Se usa el gestor de errores interno
        return null;
    }
            
    // [Recomendado] Desactivamos temporalmente (evitamos bucle infinito)
    set_error_handler('errorHandlerOff', E_ALL);
    
    // Manejo del error (ej: mandar mail, escribir archivo log, etc.)
            
    // Reactivamos
    set_error_handler('errorHandlerOn', E_ALL);

    // Aqui es donde indicas si continuas con el gestor interno
    return true;
}
set_error_handler('errorHandlerOn', E_ALL);
```

***Nota:** Esto lo tienes que realizar al principio de todo, antes de cualquier otra cosa*